# Where are the "0" gone?

Tags: ruby

```
str = "Blah00blah001"
str1 = ""
str1 = str.gsub(/[0-9]+$/,'')

print str.chars
puts
print str1.chars
puts

print str.chars - str1.chars
```

output

```
["B", "l", "a", "h", "0", "0", "b", "l", "a", "h", "0", "0", "1"]
["B", "l", "a", "h", "0", "0", "b", "l", "a", "h"]
["1"]
```

what I was expecting in the last print

```
["0","0","1"]
```

What I got

```
["1"]
```

Why is it so?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but there's definitely some zeros in `str1`.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? What do you mean by "why is it so"? What I mean by that is, what answer do you expect, other than "because that's what the documentation of the method says"?

Comment: Note `[1,0,1,0,1,1] - [0,1] #=> []`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick quote from the documentation of [`Array#-`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-2D):

> **ary - other_ary → new_ary**
>
> Returns a new array that is a copy of the original array, removing any items that also appear in `other_ary`. The order is preserved from the original array.

The example posted after the description shows how it works (the same as it works with your arrays):

> ```
> [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 ] - [ 1, 2, 4 ]  #=>  [ 3, 3, 5 ]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

That's the expected result - `-` functions like the set difference, removing all elements that appear in the second array.
Check out the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-2D).